# How to deal with binary classification with large difference in label counts

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I feel like this might have been asked but I don't know how to search it. Basically I'm building a binary classifier using Random Forest, and there are many, many more positive results than negative ones (2k vs ~20). The accuracy is of course very good, since the test set usually has 0-1 negative examples and over a thousand positive ones. If machine learning is still viable for this situation, what is the best approach to handling such a small number of negative cases? Or is the data just useless?

Comment: Start by googling "class imbalance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, your dataset has the imbalanced distribution of the classes(2k vs ~20). This distribution does not allow you to build the predictive model as the model treat your rare event (negative results) as the random noise and couldn't predict well for the new data set.

You may have to upsample the rare event to make it balanced in the distribution before building any predictive model. You can still try a random forest model which works well for the imbalanced dataset as well but I don't think 20 vs ~2k distributions work well in the random forest as well. You can get the more detailed information about dealing with the imbalanced data distribution, you can follow this link: https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes

The sample code to upsample your data would be something like this:

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
# Separate majority and minority classes
df_minority = df[df.pos_neg==0] #I classified negative class as '0'
df_majority = df[df.pos_neg==1]

# Upsample minority class
df_minority_upsampled = resample(df_minority, 
                                 replace=True,       # sample with replacement
                                 n_samples=11828,    # to match majority class
                                 random_state=123)   # reproducible results

# Combine majority class with upsampled minority class
df_upsampled = pd.concat([df_majority, df_minority_upsampled])

# Display new class counts
df_upsampled.value_counts()
# 1    2000
# 0    2000
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried sklearn's SMOTE as well after some googling but it looks like upscaling this way isn't affecting anything. I did however find a possible solution that is specific to my dataset.